# JSON syntax with AJAX call and jquery each loop

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an AJAX call that returns the data from PHP

```
echo json_encode( $json_response);
```

and the result is as follows

[{"name":"Sprouts.......}]

I then loop through it with JQUERY

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(i, obj) {
         var name = (obj.name);
         var address = (obj.address);        
        });
```

This works perfectly fine, but I am trying to add a name (child) to it so that I can have other children.  I used the following

`json_encode(array('storedata' => $json_response))`

to add the name storedata which returns

{"storedata":[{"name":"Sprouts....

I have tried looping through with

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data.storedata), function(i, obj) {
             var name = (obj.name);
             var address = (obj.address);        
            });
```

but something is wrong with the syntax because the data.storedata is undefined.

What is the correct syntax and/or correct way to do this.  Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Don't show partial code followed by ellipsis, write the entire code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks Julien updated with full code.  Please let me know if anything else is missing to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `storedata` before parsing the string into an object, so you need to replace `$.parseJSON(data.storedata)` with `$.parseJSON(data).storedata`:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data).storedata, function(i, obj) {
         var name = (obj.name);
         var address = (obj.address);        
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me hours of head banging on the desk.  Knew it had to be something I was missing.